# How do I check if name or email exists and if it does, stop current action? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I set up authentication using this guide...
https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014

I want to verify if name or email already exists.
If it does not exist, I want it to go ahead and create user.
If it does exist, I want it to stop and do something else.

I do not want to create duplicate users.

I set up a model with this:
    rails generate model user name email password_digest

I have this in my users controller:

```
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end
```

Here is my /users/new.html.erb

## Signup!

```
<%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>

  Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
  Email: <%= f.text_field :email %>
  Password: <%= f.password_field :password %>
  Password Confirmation: <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

I have tried some things like this in my users controller with no luck:

```
  def create
    if Users.where?(:name => user)
      redirect_to 'articles'
    else
      user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to '/'
      else
        redirect_to '/signup'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You can trigger an `ajax` call upon `keyup` to check the `name` or `email`. If true, you can display an error immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to validate email ensuring uniqueness true. By so doing, any attempt to create a user with that email will throw an error.

Add to your user model:

`validates_uniqueness_of :email` or `validates :email, uniqueness: true`

Comment: How exactly do I add that?  $ rails g migration add_validates_to_user validates :email, uniqueness: true        Then run rake db:migrate?

Comment: Just copy any one of the two to your User model

Comment: I'm glad it works. Please like the answer and accept it since it does.

Comment: Beware of Concurrency: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 3):

Might be worth it noting that `validates :email, uniqueness: true` only works if it is the only validation in your model.

If you, for example, ask for a nickname too and require the nickname to be present (`validates :nickname, presence: true`) than the validation might fail, because the nickname is missing although the email is unique. That might lead to unexpected behavior.

I recommend using a uniqueness validation in your model, just to be safe. But to answer if a user with a certain email already exists, I would suggest asking the User model exactly that:

```
if User.exists?(email: params[:user][:email])
  # ...
```

Comment: This answer is good to check in migrations for example where you might want to populate a record with a value if it doesn't have one already. Thanks!